# "findLibrary returned null" on Android while connecting to deezer's player-module

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, deezer

I'm trying to establish a player-module from an android device to the music-streaming-platform deezer. This is the Tutorial I followed: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/android#using-player-module-2

(See the question at the bottom)

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.playertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnect;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnectImpl;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerError;
import com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException;
import com.deezer.sdk.player.Player;
import com.deezer.sdk.player.PlayerFactory;
import com.deezer.sdk.player.TooManyPlayersExceptions;
import com.deezer.sdk.player.impl.DefaultPlayerFactory;
import com.deezer.sdk.player.networkcheck.WifiOnlyNetworkStateChecker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final static String APP_ID = "XXXXX";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DeezerConnect connection = new DeezerConnectImpl(APP_ID);

    try {
        PlayerFactory player = new DefaultPlayerFactory(getApplication(), connection, new WifiOnlyNetworkStateChecker());
        Player play = player.createPlayer();

        //same as: Player player = new DefaultPlayerFactory(getApplication(), connection, new WifiOnlyNetworkStateChecker()).createPlayer();
    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DeezerError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TooManyPlayersExceptions e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.playertest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.playertest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here the logcat output:

```
07-20 12:49:29.755: E/Trace(4186): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 12:49:30.925: W/dalvikvm(4186): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/deezer/sdk/player/impl/RealPlayerImpl;
07-20 12:49:30.985: W/dalvikvm(4186): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at com.deezer.sdk.player.impl.DefaultPlayerFactory.createPlayer(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at com.example.playertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load deezer from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.playertest-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.playertest-1]: findLibrary returned null
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at com.deezer.sdk.player.impl.RealPlayerImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:49:31.125: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     ... 16 more
```

I'm very confused about this failure, because if I delete the line

```
Player play = player.createPlayer();
```

there is no failure and no warning. So this is the interesting point. 
I don't get why the returned library at this point is null, because the classes DeezerConnect, DeezerConnectImpl, PlayerFactory, DefaultPlayerFactory and even Player are all in the same library and up to this point everything works fine.

Has anybody an obvious solution for this? Moreover, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the steps [Adding the SDK C library](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/android#adding-sdk-c-library), namely adding the libdeezer.so to your libs/armeabi folder?

This error mostly means that the library is not found on the device, which in your case might mean that it is not packaged with your app.